# Add admins to telegram channel - Gram-js

Tags: node.js, telegram

I am using gram-js for creating template channels. I got almost all the functionality I wanted, but I do not get to add admins.

The idea is to add some bots as group admin by default.

Any idea of how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got the solution to my problem.

For adding an admin to a group or channel we have to use the function [EditAdmin](https://gram.js.org/tl/channels/EditAdmin)